# How does this code work between two process?

Tags: c, linux

I am doing some practice and got this code recently.

```
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 25
#define READ_END 0
#define WRITE_END 1

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){                                    
    if (argc==2){                                                   
        char output[BUFFER_SIZE];                                   
        close(4);                                                   
        while(1){
            read(3,output,BUFFER_SIZE);                             
            if(output[0]=='Q'&&output[1]==NULL){                    
                return 0;
            }
            printf("%s\n",output);                                  
        }
    }

    if(argc==1){                                                    
        char write_msg[BUFFER_SIZE]="A";                            
        int fd[2];                                                  
        pid_t pid;                                                  

        if(pipe(fd)==-1){                                           
            fprintf(stderr,"Pipe failed");
            return 1;
        }

        pid = fork();                                               

        if(pid<0){                                                  
            fprintf(stderr,"Fork failed");
            return 1;
        }

        if(pid>0){                                                  
            close(fd[READ_END]);                                    
            while (write_msg[0]!='Q'||write_msg[1]!=NULL){          
                scanf("%s",write_msg);                              
                write(fd[WRITE_END],write_msg,strlen(write_msg)+1); 
            }

            close(fd[WRITE_END]);                                   
        }
        if(pid==0){                                                 
            execl("/usr/bin/xterm","xterm","-e",argv[0],"1",NULL); 
        }
        return 0;
        }
}
```

I want to ask that how does this work. In my opinion, pipe can communicate between parent process and child process. But the chile proecss in this execute the `execlp` function to open a new terminal window and run the same program sequentially. The new window isn't the child of the parent process. However, it can receive the string from the pipe file descriptor. I can't understand why and wanna know that how does it work between two process.

I've been confused for a while.
Hope someone could help me. Thanks.

Comment: this kind of expression: `write_msg[1]!=NULL)` will NEVER happen.  write_msg[] is an array of characters and NULL is a pointer to address 0.  A pointer is never a character.

Comment: tis line, near the top of main(), `close(4);` is trash because file descriptor 4 has not been opened

Comment: this line: `read(3,output,BUFFER_SIZE);` is very suspect because no files have been opened (except the standard 0=stdin, 1=stdout, and 2=stderr.)

Comment: this expression: `output[1]==NULL)` will never happen (see my prior comment.  Perhaps you meant: `output[1]=='\0')`

Comment: calls to system functions should always be checked for error indications.  The function: `read()`, if it read any characters, returns a count of the number characters read.  That should be checked rather than assuming that characters were actually read.

Comment: in C, buffer offsets start with 0 and end at (length of buffer -1).  So this line: `char write_msg[BUFFER_SIZE]="A";` is placing the char `A` one past the end of the buffer.  This results in undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: code should not depend on the OS to cleanup.  Rather the code should cleanup (calls to `free()`, `close()`, etc.)  the exit point that displays the message "Fork failed" should be calling `close()` on each end of the pipe. I.E. `close(fd[0]);` and `close(fd[1]);`

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  When using the "%s" input/conversion specifier, always include a MAX CHARACTERS that is one less than the length of the input buffer to avoid any buffer overflow.  A buffer overflow is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event

Comment: the parent process, if it exits before the child process will make the child process a zombie  zombie processes are very difficult to eliminate/kill without rebooting the computer.  Suggest at the end of the parent processing to insert the statements: `int status; wait( &status );`

Answer (score 1):

> But the child proccss in this execute the execlp function to open a new terminal window and run the same program sequentially. The new window isn't the child of the parent process.

That's not right. The new window *is* the child process. `execl()` just replaces the child process with another process image but it's still the child process. So, the parent and child can communicate via the pipe. Your code is classic example and parent and child can communicate via unix pipe.

The child process executes the `if (argc==2){ ... }` code because it's given an arugment (in `execl()` -- so its argc is 2). The parent process is intended to be run with no arguments.

By the way, there are a couple of issues:

1) You probably want to check if `output[1]` is `\0` (null byte), not NULL. That'd make sense in order to terminate the communication (and the processes) by inputting `Q`.
So, this:

```
 if(output[0]=='Q'&&output[1]==NULL){
```

should be:

```
 if(output[0] == 'Q'&&output[1] == '\0'){
```

2) Similarly,

```
  while (write_msg[0]!='Q'||write_msg[1]!=NULL){
```

should be:

```
  while (write_msg[0] != 'Q' || write_msg[1] != '\0'){
```

Comment: oh, i got it. So in the beginning my idea is wrong. Thank you for your comment.
 I have two more problem.

 1) I tested that thepid of process running in xterm windows is not the original pid of child process. Is it one of the child of the parent process?

 2) If i use the `system` to call the xterm and execute the program instead, can it running as this code similarly? Or there are something different between two way?

 Sorry about that a lots question and Thank you agian!

Comment: or use `strcmp(output, "Q")`

Comment: @Yoohao The child process is the one you exec'ed which is `xterm` and `xterm` again forks and exec's *your* program (the one that writes to the x window). SO, obviously, the PID are different. `system()` instead of execl() can provide similar functionality way but isn't good approach because `system()` will fork again and execute the *command* via a shell you give  as a child and wait for the child to finish -- which, as you can see, involves unnecessary fork and exec'ing a shell where a simple exec could do.

Comment: Thanks a lots. And you mentioned that doing `system` involves unnecessary fork. If involving unnecessary fork, does it result in any consequence? Thank you for your help and answer, agiain.

Comment: @Yoohao Any unnecessary operation adds overhead: wastes CPU cycles, memory, starves other processes for resources, etc. Inefficient code is the consequence ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The `xterm` executed by the child *is* a child of the original program. The `fork`, then `exec` is the normal way to start another process on Unix-like systems.

When the program forks, another copy of it appears. The only difference between them is the return value from `fork`. Here, the child then replaces itself with `xterm`, setting the arguments so that `xterm` starts another copy of the original program. As long as `xterm` doesn't mess with the file descriptors of the pipe, they stay open and are inherited to whatever process xterm runs.

The one-argument version (`argc==2`) of the main program trusts that the pipe file descriptors get numbers 3 and 4, which would be the usual result, assuming the original program didn't have any fd's open apart from stdin, stdout and stderr. This isn't robust, though. To do it properly you'd want to give the fd numbers to the child as command line arguments or through the environment; or use `dup2()` in the parent to make sure the pipe is open on fd's 3 and 4.

Comment: Note that POSIX requires the file descriptors are allocated sequentially. So, the given code is quite safe to assume 3 and 4 are fds of pipe. But I agree this may not be the best approach *in general* if there are going to fds closed/opened. One way to break is to run as: `./main </dev/null` ;-)

Comment: @usr, plain redirecting wouldn't affect the fd numbers, you'd need to do something like `<&-` to close the fd or `3</dev/null` to open a new one. But yes, it works as long as the main program only inherits the usual three fd's.